# CKEditor custom config not working in draft-workspace

Tags: ckeditor, typo3-8.x

I created a custom config file for CKEditor using a yaml-file as suggested and registered it in my extension for my custom elements.

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['custom_rte'] = 'fileadmin/templates/css/custom_rte.yaml';
```

This works fine as long as I'm in the default workspace.

When I switch to the draft workspace and save an element, the config is lost and I get the default Toolbar, without my custom css and buttons.

Any idea what this could cause?

Typo3 8.7.15

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually pretty easy.

I had to set the default preset for the CKEditor in the extension, instead of using the custom one and then set that in the Page TSConfig.

So this works (in ext_localconf.php)

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['default'] = 'fileadmin/templates/css/custom_rte.yaml';
```

That way the CKEditor always uses my custom yaml-file. No Page TSConfig needed.